# System.Web.HttpException in asp.net mvc 2 on images and javascript files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, elmah

Hi I am getting the following errors reported by ELMAH on my asp.net mvc 2 site for javascript files, images etc.

> System.Web.HttpException: The remote
>   host closed the connection

I have done some research and it appears that the user/bot is clicking a link on the site before the page has fully loaded. Now this error never occurs on a controller action but always on a file that is on disk. e.g.

```
/Content/CmsImages/logo.png
/Content/CmsImages/MemberImages/Photo-001605.jpg
/Content/jquery.tickertype.js
```

So this means that all static files are being routed through the mvc pipeline.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define routes to ignore files in the Content folder.

```
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder="content" });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Does this handle all files in /content including all sub dirs and files?

Comment: I believe so as it will ignore anything after /content/*

Comment: +1 Thanks for this, have accepted this as answer as it appears to have stopped all errors coming out of this dir